# win10 keyboard short cut to delete row in word/outlook table?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there a way to delete rows in a table in word/outlook using keyboard shortcuts? I can use backspace to get there but still need to navigate to 'delete row'

Answer (score 0):

Select row / cursor at the right place. then

<kbd>Alt</kbd> (then let go, menu alphabet will show up) , <kbd>J</kbd> , <kbd>L</kbd> , <kbd>D</kbd> , <kbd>R</kbd>

Should do.

Pls share if it works/not in ur version. ( :

Answer (score 0):

Method1:
Place the cursor anywhere in the row of the table you want to delete, then press **Alt->J->L->D->R** in order .

Method2:
Select the cells in the row (or several rows) and drag the cursor to outside the table in such a way that the entire row (or rows) along with a small area outside the table boundary is highlighted. Then press backspace. The entire row (or rows) will be deleted in one go.

Hope the above will help you:)

Comment: Do the suggestions above help?

I'd appreciate it if you choose the most helpful post above and mark it as the best answer, this will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well. 

Thanks!  :)

Comment: Is there any update on this thread? If the issue has been resolved, please mark the helpful replies as answers, this will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well.